# iOS app is rejected as "Spam"

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ios-appstore

I have similar apps with different design & color theme as per my different client. But Apple is now rejected my latest app as **spam**

Apple message:

> ### Guideline 4.3 - Design - Spam
>
> We noticed that your app provides the same feature set as other apps
> you've submitted to the App Store; it simply varies in content or
> language, which is considered a form of spam.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> When creating multiple apps where content is the only varying element,
> you should offer a single app to deliver differing content to
> customers. Alternatively, you may consider creating a web app, which
> looks and behaves similar to a native app when the customer adds it to
> their Home screen. Refer to the Configuring Web Applications section
> of the Safari Web Content Guide for more information.
>
> You will experience a delayed review process if you deliberately
> disregard the App Store Review Guidelines, ignore previous rejection
> feedback in future app submissions, or use your app to mislead or
> deceive users.
>
> **Important Information**
>
> As a result of violating this guideline, your app’s review has been
> delayed. Future submissions of this app, and other apps associated
> with your Apple Developer account, will also experience a delayed
> review. Deliberate disregard of the App Store Review Guidelines and
> attempts to deceive users or undermine the review process are
> unacceptable and is a direct violation Section 3.2(f) of the Apple
> Developer Program License Agreement. Continuing to violate the Terms &
> Conditions of the Apple Developer Program will result in the
> termination of your account, as well as any related or linked
> accounts, and the removal of all your associated apps from the App
> Store.
>
> We want to provide a safe experience for users to get apps and a fair
> environment for all developers to be successful. If you believe we
> have misunderstood or misinterpreted the intent of your app, you may
> submit an appeal for consideration or provide additional clarification
> by responding directly to this message in Resolution Center in iTunes
> Connect.
>
> For app design information, check out the following videos: "Best
> Practices for Great iOS UI Design" and "Designing Intuitive User
> Experiences," available on the Apple Developer website.
>
> You may also want to review the iOS Human Interface Guidelines for
> more information on how to create a great user experience in your app.

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: Note that you actually agreed to not publish Apple's review messages when you accepted the Apple Developer Agreement.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how many apps you publish. 3 or 300 might make it clear what’s happening. It seems the guidance here is crystal clear - why can’t you resolve this with the review team or your internal team?

Answer (score 6):

The guidance is really quite straightforward. You need to do what is listed under "Next steps" and/or communicate with the Apple review team to solve the issue, primarily

> When creating multiple apps where content is the only varying element, you should offer a single app to deliver differing content to customers

Basically you're in violation of the guidelines as having multiple identical apps with only color theme variations is not allowed. You could instead create a single app where the user can select the color theme they wish if you agree with the characterization of multiple similar apps.

If you don’t agree then a chat with Dev support or a formal appeal would be your next step.

Comment: but theme is as per my different client. Different apps for different client.

Comment: Make one app which can be configured per client

Comment: but how can I sell single app to multiple client with changed theme. I don't want to show the same app to other client. all apps needs to separateas per client.

Comment: Don't publish your client apps under your own account. Each client should publish his own apps under his own name.

Comment: Creating a separate account still violates the rule.  I should know cause they rejected based on same problem.

Comment: No, it doesn't really violate *this* specific rule. If you try to publish an app that's basically the same as some competitor's app and just has some visual style changes, Apple *might*, IIRC, reject it as well, but it won't be considered as **spam**. Also, then it would be more of a problem between you and your competitor, copyright and whatnot. However, there's no hard rule stopping you from doing the 100th calculator or whatever just because somebody else has done it. In any way, it's bad, bad practice to publish app's in a client's name under your own account. Don't do it.

Comment: @Gero Well, it was rejected by Apple for violating that specific rule. It seems pretty clear to me that Apple's intention with the spam rule is not to have multiple identical apps differing only in superficial changes such as logo or colours. And yes, if you're publishing for a client under your name, you're really also breaking another rule.

Comment: @jksoegaard, Ah, now I see what you mean (or rather, yup, Apple *also* calls that spam, kinda makes sense, of course, and I'm a dummy). I just meant that in OP's specific case it read "...same feature set as other apps **you've** submitted to the App Store...". There's a chance the review team wouldn't have complained if each client had submitted their "clone" on its own, that probably depends a lot on what it actually does. In some cases "similar" apps might be okay (see calculator), but I'm not saying it's guaranteed to work. Not a good business model in general for sure.

Comment: @Gero Well, Apples guidelines specially say that you should not spam the App Store with similar apps. In this case the apps are identical except for colours - but even your calculator example would be a kind of "spam". I.e. Apple specifically states that they have enough "burp" apps and "flashlight" app - so don't bother making more of these, even though they are slightly different than the existing ones.

Comment: @jksoegaard Yup, yup, I just derped there. Of course that would be spam. However, ultimately it's to some extent subjective what is and what is not "sufficiently different". There *are still* multiple calculators out there, after all. From the question it reads as if OP's apps have a high chance to be too similar, but ultimately we don't know that. I've personally known a business that sold "apps" to small stores that were *very* similar, but since the stores were different enough and *some* things looked different, it "slipped through". OP may be lucky, but I wouldn't rely on it...

Comment: Yep, good advice... it's worth trying if you've already made the app, but in the long run it's not a good strategy.